# Unexpected ListItem in Scope

Tags: search, search-scope, fulltextsqlquery

I've defined a new scope for a search service application. The scope's got one simple rule - content type = particular content type. I'm finding that when I query this scope (FullTextSQLQuery) it's bringing back ListItem's with different content types to the one I specified, and I don't have a clue why.